# array.length returning zero even though it has a value

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

This code is returning me a length of 0 even though it has a value.

Example code:

```
for (var q = 0; q < data.data.length; q++) {
var test1 = {
    imgId: data.data.imgId,
    imgString: data.data.imgString
};
vm.imgArr.push(test1);}
```

`console.log(vm.imgArr.length); // returning zero`

Example data:

```
data.data = [
{
    "imgId": "asdasd21321312312asdad",
    "imgString": "heasjahdasdjashdjashd"
},
{
    "imgId": "asdasd21321312312asdad",
    "imgString": "heasjahdasdjashdjashd"
},
{
    "imgId": "asdasd21321312312asdad",
    "imgString": "heasjahdasdjashdjashd"
}];
```

Comment: Can you post more of your code so we can have a working verifiable example to debug?

Comment: Are you sure that loop actually ran? If `data.data` is empty, so is the result.

Comment: can you post your `data.data`

Comment: @tadman yes sir because im reading its value but not the length

Comment: You might try logging `data.data.length` to be sure it isn't 0.

Comment: What is the length of `data.data`

Comment: i think you are passing reponse as text or it is blank.

Comment: Either you're accessing a different `vm` variable, the loop didn't run, or you ran the `console.log` *before* the loop ran. Check your order of operations. Check that `data.data.length` is > 0.

Comment: I have edited and added more information thank you.

Comment: Try and log imgArr please.

Comment: Check my answer. you have missed the `index` while reading the value in for loop

Answer (score 1):

You have wrongly ready the data inside the for loop. You should get the value from `data.data` by using index `data.data[q].imgId`

try this instead of your for loop.

```
for (var q = 0; q < data.data.length; q++) {
var test1 = {
    imgId: data.data[q].imgId,
    imgString: data.data[q].imgString
};
vm.imgArr.push(test1);}
```

---

### You can check this below snippet

```js
var data={};

data.data = [
{
    "imgId": "asdasd21321312312asdad",
    "imgString": "heasjahdasdjashdjashd"
},
{
    "imgId": "asdasd21321312312asdad",
    "imgString": "heasjahdasdjashdjashd"
},
{
    "imgId": "asdasd21321312312asdad",
    "imgString": "heasjahdasdjashdjashd"
}];

var vm={imgArr:[]};
for (var q = 0; q < data.data.length; q++) {
var test1 = {
    imgId: data.data[q].imgId,
    imgString: data.data[q].imgString
};
vm.imgArr.push(test1);}

console.log(vm.imgArr);
```

Comment: Good point about accessing the array element by index. However, it doesn't explain why `vm.imgArr.length` is 0. OP's code should be pushing several objects of the form `{imgId: undefined, imgString: undefined}` onto the array.

Comment: @ted may be it throw an error.